# Snap install failure: error: cannot find signatures with metadata for snap

Tags: snap, metadata

I've been building my own snap and installing it successfully for a while now, but just today, every time I build my snap file, when I try to install it, I get...

```
error: cannot find signatures with metadata for snap "mysnap_1.0_amd64.snap"
```

I am at a complete loss.  What does this mean?  How do I fix it?  I can't think of what I've done to cause this to start happening.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Yeah this is a terribly unhelpful error, I have no idea why they haven't fixed it. It relates to "assertions" in snapd. In this case, that is the verification that the snap comes from a trusted party. Since you're installing a local snap, you have no assertions for it, and snapd doesn't trust it. Think of it a bit like sideloading Android apps, if you've ever done that.

Regardless, you can get past this during your testing with the also-terribly-named `--dangerous` flag:

```
$ sudo snap install --dangerous <snap>
```

**note:** there was some churn on this flag; in earlier releases it was `--force-dangerous`.

Comment: That got me passed the error.  Thank you!  I suppose if I had read the man page for snap I should have been able to deduce that.  So maybe the need for this flag will go away after a proper upgrade of the snap daemon?  Edit: Oh, looks like snap is still in development.

Comment: Indeed, snapd is still being developed. The need for this flag will go away once you publish your snap to the store, where it will get assertions.

Comment: This is still an error in 2020.

Please replace the message with one that actually describes the problem!